# Show similar content on multiple sites

Tags: 7, nodes, multi-sites

I have 10 different sites with different databases, each site is for a particular location/country like us.example.com.
And I have a main site (example.com) which will show content from all sites.
Content posted on main site will be visible on a site if address in content is filled with sub site country like USA.

For example I have a content type Projects which has a field for country, now if I add a project on main site example.com and select US as country then this content should now be visible on us.example.com.

So basically I need to share content between multiple sites only for a single content type with some conditions.
Is there any method/article/plugin available to get this done ?

I am trying to write a custom module but not sure from where to start.
I also tried it with feeds (xml files) generated daily but not sure if it is a good approach.

Comment: `Service/Deploy` module is an option to share content between sites. But in your case how the content is shared between site?